# Linking SDL_image errors

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, sdl-image

I am running into problems when linking SDL_image in gcc 3 on cygwin under Windows 7.

I receive the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_image
```

My makefile appears as this:

```
all: rabbit

rabbit: main.o rabbit.o renderer.o
        g++ -o rabbit main.o rabbit.o renderer.o -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image 

main.o: main.cpp rabbit.h 
        g++ -c main.cpp 

rabbit.o: rabbit.cpp rabbit.h gameobject.h
        g++ -c rabbit.cpp

renderer.o: renderer.cpp renderer.h
        g++ -c renderer.cpp 

clean:
        rm -rf *o rabbit
```

I store SDL_image.dll, SDL_image.lib, jpeg.dll, libpng12-0.dll, libtiff-3.dll, and zlib1.dll in the directory with my executable.  SDL_image.h is also in the correct location.

Please help, this has been at fault for a few days now!

Answer (score 2):

**SDL_image** is not part of the core SDL distribution. It must be installed separately.

Check if you have `/usr/local/lib/libSDL_image.a` or the shared library installed.

Comment: In that directory I have SDL_image.lib?

Comment: Then you must add this library path to your compilation line: `g++ -o rabbit main.o rabbit.o renderer.o -L/usr/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image`. If that doesn't work, try to pass it as `SDL_image.lib` or `-lSDL_image.lib`

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer. There's a check box right next to the question. Click on it to select my answer as the official.